# How to increase the font size in PlotMakers

Tags: plotting, legending

When I use `PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledCircle], 40}` in `ListPlot` I get something like this:

[image]

How can I increase the font size of those numbers shown in the photo?

Comment: I'm not following. How do you generate that picture to begin with? Can you supply us with the code required to do that?

Comment: It's easy. In `ListPlot` I plot 3 data set and give each a different color, then I use `PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledCircle], 40}`. The picture shown is cropped.

Comment: If I'm following you correctly, you can alter the size of the markers by listing them individually, e.g. `PlotMarkers -> ({\[FilledCircle], #}&/@{40, 60, 80})`. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: By doing what you have suggested the size of the circles increases too. I want to keep the size of those circles constant and independently increase the size of numbers.

Comment: How are you labeling the points? Is this part of a Legend?

Comment: yashar, why not just give a small code example. There are a tons of reasons for doing so.

Comment: O.K. I should have added more explanation. I found the solution. I should have used `PlotLegends`. My question was wrong I think. I will delete the question. Thank you for comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ListPlot[List /@ Transpose[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}], 
 PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledCircle], 40},
 PlotRangePadding -> 1,
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Style[#, 40] & /@ {"53ps", "211ps", "739ps"}]]
```

[image]

or, use `LabelStyle` option of `PointLegend`:

```
ListPlot[List /@ Transpose[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}], 
 PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledCircle], 40},
 PlotRangePadding -> 1,
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{"53ps", "211ps", "739ps"}, LabelStyle -> 40]]
(* same picture *)
```